# How do I define a gradle build script environment variable from a file in my src/main/resources directory?

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, build-script

I'm using Gradle 2.7 on Windows 7.  I have a properties file, "src/main/resources/liquibase.properties", whose properties I would like to reference in my build.gradle script.  So for instance in my properties file I have

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db
username=myuser
password=mypass
```

I would like to reference these in my script like so ...

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-1.0.xml'
      url '${url}'
      username '${username}'
      password '${password}'
    }
  }
}
```

Also I would like to do this by just runing "gradle build" without having to specify any additional parameters on teh command line.  How can I do this?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: You should rather put a file liquibase.properties under project root. Then, this file can be used in build.gradle directly and should be used to filter (`ReplaceTokens`) a project properties file under `src/main/resources`. build.gradle shouldn't read project resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the properties file then get the values from that... Here is an example

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
      File propsFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties")
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-1.0.xml'
      url properties['url']
      username properties['username']
      password properties['password']
    }
  }
}
```